# I want to limit the display of x and y axis in R

Tags: r, plot, raster

I am trying to Limit the x and y axis in R but dont know how to do so,I am using xlim and ylim but it is not working.

here is my code:

```
library(raster)
library(changepoint)
r <- raster("E:/Project_data/all_India_raster_stacked_image.tif")
set.seed(1)
m1=values(r)
m1.amoc=cpt.mean(m1)
cpts(m1.amoc)
m1.cusum=cpt.mean(m1,pen.value=1,penalty=manual,test.stat='CUSUM')
dev.new(width=10,height=10,unit='cm')
plot(m1.amoc,xlim(0,800),ylim(400000,1500000))
```

Comment: Is that the problem? `xlim=c(0,800), ylim=c(400000,1500000)`

Comment: @MKR this is correct - make it an answer and get the reputation. :)

Answer (score 0):

plot(m1.amoc,xlim=c(0,800), ylim=c(400000,1500000))